# Fields with @JsonProperty are ignored on deserialization in Spring Boot + Spring Data Rest

Tags: jackson, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I found that in Spring Boot + Spring Data Rest, fields with @JsonProperty are still ignored on deserialization. Without using Spring Boot, the bug has been fixed. See issue tracker: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-320

I created a minimal demo project to reproduce the bug in Spring Boot 1.2.3.RELEASE. Shorcut: https://github.com/cdcorg/JsonPropertyBug/blob/master/src/main/java/demothree/domain/Entity.java#L21

Enable @JsonProperty will make it impossible to alter the property(by using HTTP PUT)

If I set

```
spring.jackson.mapper.USE_ANNOTATIONS=false
```

and try to update the properties, Spring Data Rest will say:

```
{
"cause": {
    "cause": {
        "cause": null,
        "message": "Unrecognized field "family" (class demothree.domain.Entity), 
        not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "fname", "id", "name"])n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: demothree.domain.Entity["family"])"
    },
    "message": "Could not read payload!; 
    nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: 
    Unrecognized field "family" (class demothree.domain.Entity), 
    not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "fname", "id", "name"])n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: demothree.domain.Entity["family"])"
},
"message": "Could not read an object of type class demothree.domain.Entity from the request!; 
nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read payload!; 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "family" (class demothree.domain.Entity), not marked as ignorable 
(3 known properties: "fname", "id", "name"])n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: demothree.domain.Entity["family"])"
```

}

Stack trace:

```
2015-04-16 11:50:00.391 ERROR 8420 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.d.r.w.AbstractRepositoryRestController : Could not read an object of type class demothree.domain.Entity from the request!; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read payload!; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "family" (class demothree.domain.Entity), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "fname", "id", "name"])
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: demothree.domain.Entity["family"])

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read an object of type class demothree.domain.Entity from the request!; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read payload!; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "family" (class demothree.domain.Entity), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "fname", "id", "name"])
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: demothree.domain.Entity["family"])
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.readPutForUpdate(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:197)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.read(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:169)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:879)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read payload!; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "family" (class demothree.domain.Entity), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "fname", "id", "name"])
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: demothree.domain.Entity["family"])
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.merge(DomainObjectReader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.readPut(DomainObjectReader.java:129)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.JsonPatchHandler.applyPut(JsonPatchHandler.java:133)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.readPutForUpdate(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:194)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "family" (class demothree.domain.Entity), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "fname", "id", "name"])
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: demothree.domain.Entity["family"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:51)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:744)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:915)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1306)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1284)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:211)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1271)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:971)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.doMerge(DomainObjectReader.java:191)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.DomainObjectReader.merge(DomainObjectReader.java:135)
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

Can anyone confirm on this? Any help is highly appreciated!

EDIT: Typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very strange solution:

After I switch back to Spring Data Rest 2.2.1 (contained in Spring Boot 1.2.1.RELEASE), HTTP PUT now works properly. You can verify this by changing my bug demo project's POM file.

Now I got confused:
Why didn't I reproduce the same bug by using Spring Data Rest 2.2.1 as Runar Botten did?
Why do I encounter the bug by using the latter versions(2.2.2) which are supposed to fix that??